# Change dynamically generated view column's datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've found solutions how to change view's column datatype which are created basing on existing table's columns (*cast method*). But how implement this (or another) method to the column which is generated like this by (*row_number*)

Existing code:

```
CREATE VIEW v_Test
AS
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY [Name] ) AS [ID], -- becomes bigint by default
        [Name]
    FROM [DB].[dbo].[TestTable]
```

By default `ID` column created as a bigint type. I need to have it as `int` type

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) as using `bigint` as its [return [data\] type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#return-types). If you want to change that data type, you need to wrap the function in a `CAST`/`CONVERT`. Why can't you do that?

Comment: cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY [Name] ) as int) should work

Comment: @siggemannen .. Thanks. Wrapping which is simple and at last works

Comment: thanks to @Larnu mostly, i just spelled it out :)

Comment: There are no "dynamically generated" columns. SQL is strongly typed. The columns and their types are determined at the time the query is first compiled into an execution plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROW_NUMBER is documented as using bigint as its return [data] type. If you want to change that data type, you need to wrap the function in a CAST/CONVERT.

```
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY [Name] ) as int)
```

should work.